# How to get excluded attributes of factory after generation?

Tags: python, testing, sqlalchemy, factory-boy

I use [Factory Boy](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to generate a fake user. I need a field `password` that should be hashed (in db, this is the only row related to the password) and a `clear_password` value in order to know what is the associated clear password of the hashed one for later use in tests.

I tried two similar method, the [class `Params`](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#simple-parameters) and the [meta option `exclude`](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#factory.FactoryOptions.exclude). Only exclude works in order to generate a clear password later hashed. The issue: I can't access the `clear_password` after object generation.

#### requirements.txt

```
passlib[bcrypt]
SQLAlchemy
factory-boy
```

#### Minimum reproductible example (python 3.10 working with last version of requirements)

```py
import random

import factory
import passlib.context
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import orm

engine = sa.create_engine(
    'sqlite:///test.db',
    echo=True,
)

Base = orm.declarative_base(bind=engine)
pwd_context = passlib.context.CryptContext(schemes=['bcrypt'], deprecated='auto')

BCRYPT_MAX_LENGTH = 72


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    password = sa.Column(sa.LargeBinary(BCRYPT_MAX_LENGTH), nullable=False)
    ...


class UserFact(factory.Factory):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        exclude = ('clear_password',)

    clear_password = factory.Faker('password', length=random.randint(8, 64))
    password = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda o: bytes(
        pwd_context.hash(o.clear_password), encoding='utf-8'))
    ...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(UserFact().clear_password)
```

#### Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/to/file.py", line 38, in <module>
    print(User().clear_password)
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'clear_password'
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it might not be the answer you are looking for but, how about assigning a fixed (ie. predictible) value to `clear_password` ?

From your question, you don't seem to want to test `passlib` implementation, so having the same password for all `User`s generated during tests should be ok.

---

For your initial question, you cannot access excluded members because upon
generation, factories return their underlying model and not the factory itself. However you could monkey-patch the returned model like so :

```py
# rest of code omitted
class UserFact(Factory):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        exclude = ('clear_password',)

    clear_password = Faker('password', length=random.randint(8, 64))
    password = LazyAttribute(lambda o: bytes(
        pwd_context.hash(o.clear_password), encoding='utf-8'))
    
    @classmethod
    def _generate(cls, create, kwargs):
        # Forcing the evaluation of the provider outside of the
        # _generate call in order to store the value and pass it as a kwarg
        clear_password = kwargs.get("clear_password", cls.clear_password.evaluate(None, None, {"locale": "fr"}))
        user = super()._generate(create, {**kwargs, "clear_password": clear_password})
        # Monkey-patching the generated model
        user._clear_password = clear_password
        return user


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # no password
    print("uf = UserFact()")
    uf = UserFact()
    print(f'uf._clear_password : {uf._clear_password}')
    print(f"Verified : {pwd_context.verify(uf._clear_password, uf.password)}")
    
    # clear_password in kwargs
    print('uf = UserFact(clear_password="test")')
    uf = UserFact(clear_password="test")
    print(f'uf._clear_password : {uf._clear_password}')
    print(f"Verified : {pwd_context.verify(uf._clear_password, uf.password)}")
```

Comment: "having the same password" I did this, but I didn't want to write code doing that. It works, but force me to have a hardcoded password in my tests, and I tried to avoid this.

Of course I don't test passlib implementation, but I want to test a "auth" API endpoint with a code as simple as possible. I would prefer a `"password": fake_user.password' instead of `"password": 'VALID_PASSWORD' in the login_data I send to the API endpoint because it's more "sure" that it's the correct password. Any change for the "hardcoded" password require changes everywhere, and common constant is boilerplate.

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't works, because the `cls.clear_password` is a `factory.faker.Faker` object, not the generated value.

Comment: You are right ! My bad. It updated the answer.

Comment: 1 step closer, but unfortunatly, your code create a new clear_password, unrelated with the hashed password. Maybe I'm wrong, but my API return a `BadUsernameOrPasswordException`, and I checked, I think I send the clear_password correctly. This error occurs when the clear_password verification return False, e.g. wrong password.

Comment: I feel like an idiot for not testing it properly. The call to `super.generate` evaluates the faker provider once and then I re-evaluated it when assigning to the private variable.I updated the answer again. Hope it helps.

Comment: Any particular reason you create a new dict instead of changing the `kwargs['clear_password']` value directly?

Comment: Nope no reason ^^`